# What is exactly created by this ByteBuffer.allocate() method?

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

into a Java application I found this line:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / 8);
```

It creats a **ByteBuffer** object (that I think is used to read and write single byte. So what it means? That I can put and read only bytes in this object?).

So the **ByteBuffer.allocate()** method seems to be something like a factory method that return a Byte.

But what exactly is allocating passing the **Integer.SIZE / 8** value as input parameter?

Comment: No, `Integer.SIZE` is 32, so that's creating a 4-byte buffer. And no, it's not returning a `Byte`, it's returning a `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

> what exactly is allocating passing the Integer.SIZE / 8 value as input
>   parameter?

It is creating a `ByteBuffer` instance with a 4 bytes capacity(32/8).
If you put more than one integer (or 4 bytes) in the `ByteBuffer` instance, a  `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` is thrown.

> It creates a ByteBuffer object (that I think is used to read and write
>   single byte. So what it means? That I can put and read only bytes in
>   this object?).

You can put in `byte` but also  all other primitive types except boolean : `int`, `long`, `short`, `float` and `double`.
`put(byte b)`method writes a byte.
`putInt(int value)` writes an int.
and so for..

> So the ByteBuffer.allocate() method seems to be something like a
>   factory method that return a Byte.

It is indeed a factory method but not to return a `Byte` but a `ByteBuffer` instance.
In fact, the `ByteBuffer` class is not instantiable from the client class : it is an abstract class.

So `ByteBuffer.allocate()` instantiates a implementation of the `ByteBuffer` class and returns it to the client :

```
ByteBuffer allocate = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / 8);
```

So you can write in :

```
allocate.putInt(1);
```